# What it the base technology used in electronic speaking pens?

Tags: electromagnetic

I am interesting to learn more about the technology used in electronic speaking pens which can be found as education toys for small children.
When the pen is placed over a book illustration or text, the pen will read it.

I did some research, finding interesting insight about light-pens (used on screen), but I cannot find any information on pens working with paper.

- What is technology behind this pen?
- Are circuits embed in the paper?
- Some of these pens do work at optical level, how they can detect with precision what the pen is pointing to if the tip is very narrow?

An example:
https://www.albi.eu/games/mr-pen/

Comment: Can you link to an example?

Comment: It could be RFID. Please leave a link to the one you are talking about. Thanks.

Comment: `detect with precision what the pen is pointing to` ........... probably not ...... do you know a small child that can handle the pen with precision?

Comment: please edit you question to  ask about the `pen sensor technology`, because the `pen technology` is electronics ...... always ask a precise question if possible

Comment: do you have one of those pens available for examination?

Comment: Not clear until we get a model. But I suspect if it is the same toy I have seen that it is microdot marked paper, this is the same tech behind the "smart pen" notebooks that record your notes as you write. It keeps the paper simple and child proof (can be bent , etc.) . The pen knows the location from an imperceptible pattern of microdots on the paper and an image sensor. Laser mice do something similar but they project an interfence pattern and detect the change, in this tech the pattern is imprinted on the page

Comment: over the years i have seen all kinds of sensors used in these toys .... most of them used specially printed paper .... some used printing that would appear different under IR light, some used glossiness of the print, some had conductive ink on the pages .... one was as @crasic describes, that was the Fly Pentop Computer

Comment: I have added an example in my original question

Comment: ... actually the pen is precise, can detect moving from one shape to another accurately.

Comment: @gibboK you have to be really careful using the words "precision" and "accuracy" around engineers, because they are different from each other and have very specific meanings =).  They are also subjective when inadequately defined.  Mr Pen you link to shows it works only with their books.  This makes me think they used an embedded indicator, which makes sense because the processor and software to do this optically would make the pen big.  You could likely delaminate a page of one of their books (or if they have a sample card or similar to avoid wrecking a book) and see what they've embedded.

Comment: You'll likely find some sort of RFID or proxy chip on each location that activates the pen.  There is little need for security so it's quite possible the chip just gives the pen a number/name and the pen simply plays the audio file attached to that reference number/name.

Comment: @GibboK, can you get a closeup picture of the pen tip looking end on? .... examine one of the book pages under high magnification ..... there may be a pattern of dots covering each page

Answer (score 4):

It's Anoto:

> based on its patented dot pattern technology which provides a methodology for accumulating digital big data from analogue inputs.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anoto

Comment: This is an old question. But you are right. I used to work at leapfrog. Leapfrog talking pen products including Fly, Fly Fusion, Tag, and Tag junior all used anoto. But people came to us with non-anoto prototypes. So there are competitors to anoto out there. I believe they still work more or less the same way as anoto, though. And all this is years ago now. Oh, and leapreader, too.